# Receive sms on specific port j2me

Tags: java-me, wma

I am developing j2me app. I need to receive sms on specific port. Which is the best port to define for receiving sms?
Thanks for advice

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The SMS spec ([JSR 120](http://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/final/jsr120/index2.html)) says you can't have a port that another app is using at that time, and also you can't have any of the ports that are specified in the following table.

> For security reasons, Java applications are not allowed to send SMS messages to the port numbers listed in Table A-4. Implementations MUST throw a `SecurityException` in the
>   `MessageConnection.send()` method if an application tries to send a message to any of these port numbers.
>
> **Table A-4: Port Numbers Restricted to SMS Messages**
>
> **Port number** Description
>   **2805** WAP WTA secure connection-less session service
>   **2923** WAP WTA secure session service
>   **2948** WAP Push connectionless session service (client side)
>   **2949** WAP Push secure connectionless session service (client side)
>   **5502** Service Card reader
>   **5503** Internet access conﬁguration reader
>   **5508** Dynamic Menu Control Protocol
>   **5511** Message Access Protocol
>   **5512** Simple Email Notiﬁcation
>   **9200** WAP connectionless session service
>   **9201** WAP session service
>   **9202** WAP secure connectionless session service
>   **9203** WAP secure session service
>   **9207** WAP vCal Secure
>   **49996** SyncML OTA conﬁguration
>   **49999** WAP OTA conﬁguration

Oddly, I can't see any restriction on any other values of the port number.  I'm sure this must be set out somewhere but I can't find it in the spec.

However, I strongly suggest restricting yourself to port numbers between 1 and 65535.

Answer (score 1):

Generally 5001 port is use for such operation. you can see very good example [here](http://jimmod.com/blog/2011/02/jimmys-blog-send-receiving-on-specific-port-with-j2me-application/).