# SMS Receiving Port in J2ME Mobile Application

Tags: java-me, sms, midlet, wma

Can you please explain following doubts?

1. When my j2me application is listening for sms on specific port, will it run as a server or client? Because if the two application run on same port, who will receive the sms?
2. And please suggest me, which port I should use to receive the sms, so that I would not loose any sms which is supposed to receive. Actually I have seen the answer for this same question. But I have not got the clear idea. Please suggest me on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am little bit confused. I think when your first application is listening a particular port ( suppose 5001 ) then the other application can not listen it. It might throw error.

for the second question please check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7994468/receive-sms-on-specific-port-j2me/8006244#8006244) url. This Url will tell you which port you should not listen for your development purpose.